# Magento: Fatal error issue

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5, fatal-error

I downloaded an updated module earlier and everything was going fine (except that the module wasn't working 100%) and I went to do some debugging. I started by comparing some folder from the old module with the updated module. Everything seemed to check out but there was still a mixed content error on the map page. So, as any novice who has no clue what NOT to do, I thought I would start by renaming a folder in our custom design folders from "unirgy" to "_unirgy" to somehow see if I could force it to load the default map.phtml file. This caused a

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in 
/home/lynsecom/public_html/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php 
on line 901
```

I went back and changed the folder name back to it's original name, but this error keeps coming up. I cannot get to store admin either - the same error pops up. I am clueless where to start because I just do not have a strong grasp yet of how Magento works. I am appreciative of any help I can get at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get past this fatal error, I'd suggest disabling the module that was causing you trouble.

1. Navigate to `/home/lynsecom/public_html/store/app/etc/modules/` and locate the module declaration file. It'll follow the naming convention [Package]_[Modulename].xml
2. In that xml file, find the `<active>true</active>` node and change it to `<active>false</active>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I do not have an app/etc/modules/ folder. It stops at app/etc/ and only contains the config.xml and 3 types of the local.xml file.

Comment: So, after banging my head against the desk for a bit, I kept coming back to your answer and kept wondering why I didn't have the folder structure you mentioned. So, went to my backup and there was a copy that included the folder! I literally dragged the folder over to the live site and everything worked beautifully. I have no idea how it was deleted to begin with, but now that it is back everything is working. Thank you for a sideways fix, chjohasbrouck!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you should clean your cache through your admin and delete the folders in **var/cache** since the only thing that you might have done by changing the folder name is that the Config class cannot find the proper templates defined in the xml, they could have been cached.

Comment: I cannot access my admin. I manually deleted my cache in the var/cache and still no luck.